# Integration when the integrand expression is a constant

Tags: calculus, integration

We are given that $\ln \frac{y}{x^3} = \text{const}$, where $y = y(x)$. What is $\int \ln \frac{y}{x^3} dy$? My understanding is that

$$\int \ln \frac{y}{x^3} dy =   \ln \frac{y}{x^3} \int dy = y\ln \frac{y}{x^3} + C$$

rather than

$$\int \ln \frac{y}{x^3} dy = y \left( \ln \frac{y}{x^3} - 1   \right) + C$$

Am I right?

Comment: How can $\ln\left(\dfrac{y}{x^3}\right)$ be a constant? By definition, $\int \ln\left(\dfrac{y}{x^3}\right) \, dy$ refers to the set of functions $F$ such that $F'(y)=\ln\left(\dfrac{y}{x^3}\right)$ for all $y$. The phrase "for all $y$" tells us that $y$ is a variable, not a constant. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Joe, The way I understand it is that $\ln \frac{y}{x^3}$ is a constant as the initial condition of the problem. Then, if indeed, $ln \frac{y}{x^3}$ is a constant, it, being a constant, cannot be a function of $y$ or of anything else for that matter.

Comment: If $\ln\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)$ is a constant, then $y$ is a constant, and you can't integrate a function with respect to a constant. Does $\int x^2 \, d1$ make sense to you?

Comment: I'm not trying to be obtuse—I genuinely do not understand how the expression $$\int \ln\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right) \, dy$$can be well-formed if $y$ is intended to be a constant.

Comment: @ Joe, “then  is a constant”. Not necessarily—cf. @ It's Me's answer. Otherwise, I agree with you, and that's the gist of my trouble. An expression is given which is a constant and, then, lo and behold, integration is offered of that expression (which, in its togetherness, is given to be a constant) over one of the quantities of this expression.

Comment: @Joe I really don't understand why you are putting so much pressure on the OP. It is clear that --as usual-- $x$ and $y$ are variables, and that there is functional relationship between the two: $y = f(x)$. There is also a special condition given, from which it follows that the function $f$ is actually given by $y = f(x) = K x^3$. As a result the integral can be performed without difficulty. What is your problem ?

Comment: @M.Wind: My problem is that I don't understand how $\ln\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)$ can be a constant. And I explicitly stated that I'm not trying to put pressure on the OP, but rather just trying to clarify what his question means.

Comment: @Joe But clearly $ln(y/x^3)$ is constant when you substitute $y = Kx^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=Kx^3 \Rightarrow dy=3Kx^2 dx$. Hence,
$$\int_{}^{}ln\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)dy=\int_{}^{}ln(K)\cdot3Kx^2 dx=Kln(K)x^3+C=y \cdot ln\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)+C$$

Comment: @ It’s Me, So, then, indeed, $\int \ln \left( \frac{y}{x^3}  \right) dy = \ln \frac{y}{x^3} \int dy = \ln \left( \frac{y}{x^3} \right) y$, as in the OP (please, notice the edit), not $\int \ln \left( \frac{y}{x^3}  \right) dy = y\left( \ln \left( \frac{y}{x^3} \right) - 1 \right)$.